# Post comment inside Django DetailView

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I need to add comments in article page. Post request receives data but not saves it.

In models.py:

```
class TemporaryComment(models.Model):
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='temporary_comment')
    email = models.EmailField()
    message = models.TextField(max_length=1500)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_approved = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

In forms.py:

```
class CommentModelForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = TemporaryComment
        fields = [
            'article',
            'email',
            'message',
        ]
```

in views.py:

```
class ArticleDetailView(FormMixin, DetailView):
    model = Article
    template_name = 'article.html'
    form_class = CommentModelForm

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('main:article', kwargs={'pk': self.object.pk})

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['last_articles'] = Article.objects.filter(is_active=True).order_by('-timestamp')[:10]
        context['comments'] = self.object.temporary_comment.filter(is_approved=True)
        context['form'] = self.get_form()
        return context

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        form = self.get_form()
        if form.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

If i comment out `article` field in forms.py, i got this error:

```
 null value in column "article_id" violates not-null 
 constraint. DETAIL:  Failing row 
 contains (18, username@email.com, check message, 2019-01-20 18:35:36.615955+00, t, null).
```

Help will be gladly accepted. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *should* comment it out, and set it in `form_valid`.

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    form.instance.article = self.object
    form.save()
    return super().form_valid(form)
```

Comment: Problem fixed. Thank you so much!